# A better way to exclude punctuation/non-alphabet characters from a string?

Tags: python-2.7

I wrote this program to catalogue and enumerate words in a text document. The code would be quite neat if I didn't have to single out every possible piece of punctuation with `string.translate()` ... is it possible, instead of excluding specific cases, to only allow alphabetical (and perhaps numerical) characters?

```
from sys import argv

script_, filename = argv

bang = open(filename, 'r+')
words = bang.read()
words = words.translate(None, ',')
words = words.translate(None, '"')
words = words.translate(None, '.')
words = words.translate(None, '...')
words = words.translate(None, '?')
words = words.translate(None, '!')
words = words.translate(None, ';')
words = words.translate(None, '-')
words = words.translate(None, '\'')
words = words.translate(None, '.\'')
words = words.translate(None, '(')
words = words.translate(None, ')')
words = words.translate(None, ':')
words = str(words)
words = words.lower()
liste = words.split()
sorte = sorted(liste)

i = 0
f = 'nullooosdfgkjlkjasdihaiwuehlfkj898'
z = 1
w = 0

for wordss in sorte:
    if f == wordss:
        z += 1
        w += 1
    elif f != wordss: 
        w += 1
        print "-", z
        z = 1
        i += 1
        print "%d. %s" % (i, wordss),
        f = wordss

print "\n\n word count - %d\n" % w
```

Comment: Do you need to support multiple languages?

Comment: I hadn't thought that far yet, but it wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to list words in a text document

How about this algorithm. Split the text on whitespace, then strip punctuation.

```
>>> text = "'I wonder how many miles I've fallen by this time?' she said aloud."
>>> import string
>>> words = [x.strip(string.punctuation) for x in text.split()]
>>> words
['I', 'wonder', 'how', 'many', 'miles', "I've", 'fallen', 'by', 'this', 'time', 'she', 'said', 'aloud']
```

See this copes with contracted words such as *don't*. So you can distinguish *we're* from *were*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the contraction issue. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex:

```
import re

cleaned_text = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', your_text)
```

Although it would be cleaner to use a regex with `Counter`:

```
>>> import re
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sentence = 'I went to the store. It was a red store.'
>>> words = re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)
>>> words
['I', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'store', 'It', 'was', 'a', 'red', 'store']
>>> Counter(words)
Counter({'store': 2, 'a': 1, 'I': 1, 'It': 1, 'to': 1, 'red': 1, 'went': 1, 'was': 1, 'the': 1})
>>> d = Counter(words)
>>> d['store']
2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`string.punctuation`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation), which I believe also takes locale into account:

```
import string

text = 'asdkjhqa23789ryh &*(Y(E%R W*YP@#*>WFKJHSF(P*H$ >'
cleaned_text = text
for p in string.punctuation:
    cleaned_text = cleaned_text.replace(p,'')
```

Comment: This works very well and returns the exact same output as my original code! Thanks. I am going to try Colonel Panic's option now though because it seems advantageous to include contractions.